# Find lowest value in array and add class

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a react component which gets props that can be value or be undefined. I need to find lowest value from array (one or more values can be undefined) and add class to the "column" list item which has the lowest value.

Let's say the object comes likes this:

```
[
 {
  "r1": [
    {
     price: 200
    }
  ],
  "r2": [
   {
    price: undefined
   }
  ],
  "r3": [
   {
    price: 1000
   }
  ]
 }
]
```

Here's my component

```
class PriceList extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
   r1Price: props.parsedOffers[`r1`],
   r2Price: props.parsedOffers[`r2`],
   r3Price: props.parsedOffers[`r3`]
  };
 }

 render() {
  return (
   <ul class="row">
    <li class="column r1">{this.state.r1Price.price ? this.state.r1Price.price : <span>-</span>}</li>
    <li class="column r2">{this.state.r2Price.price ? this.state.r2Price.price : <span>-</span>}</li>
    <li class="column r3">{this.state.r3Price.price ? this.state.r3Price.price : <span>-</span>}</li>
   </ul>
  );
 }
};

export default PriceList;
```

I expect in rendered html it should be shown like this:

```
<ul class="row">
 <li class="column r1 lowest">200</li>
 <li class="column r2">-</li>
 <li class="column r3">1000</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

add this code between `super(props)` and `this.state = {` in your constructor

```
// Finds the lowest value in the array
let lowestValue = Infinity;
for (let value in props.parsedOffers.values) {
  if (value === undefined) { continue; }

  if (value < lowestValue) { lowestValue = value }
}
```

Then you can add `lowestValue` to your object state. After that you can change your `li` elements to look like this

```html
<li className={"column r1" + (this.state.r1Price === this.state.lowestValue ? 'lowest' : ''}> ... </li>
```

Comment: Sorry, i may have provided my array ( which is actually an object) wrong. I updated the question and i didnt actually get the "add lowestValue to your object state" part ?

Comment: The new array/object structure seems weird to me, why would you have an array containing only 1 object that then contains properties which are arrays also containing 1 object with a single property. Is there a reason why it is structured that way? Also, what I ment by "add `lowestValue` to your object state" is that you need to add the variable `lowestValue` to `this.state`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my edit based on your edit. Does this work?

Here is a lint to the code: https://codesandbox.io/s/lx1x57o7mz

````
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./styles.css";
const data = {
  r1: [
    {
      price: 200
    }
  ],
  r2: [
    {
      price: undefined
    }
  ],
  r3: [
    {
      price: 1000
    }
  ]
};
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    let lowestPrice = Infinity;

    console.log("props.parsedOffers", props.parsedOffers);
    for (let record in props.parsedOffers) {
      const price = props.parsedOffers[record][0].price;
      if (price !== undefined && price < lowestPrice) {
        lowestPrice = price;
      }
    }

    this.state = {
      lowestPrice: lowestPrice,
      r1Price: props.parsedOffers[`r1`][0].price
        ? props.parsedOffers[`r1`][0].price
        : "---",
      r2Price: props.parsedOffers[`r2`][0].price
        ? props.parsedOffers[`r2`][0].price
        : "---",
      r3Price: props.parsedOffers[`r3`][0].price
        ? props.parsedOffers[`r3`][0].price
        : "---"
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ul className="row">
        <li
          class={`column r1 ${
            this.state.r1Price === this.state.lowestPrice ? "lowest" : ""
          }`}
        >
          {this.state.r1Price}
        </li>
        <li
          class={`column r2 ${
            this.state.r2Price === this.state.lowestPrice ? "lowest" : ""
          }`}
        >
          {this.state.r2Price}
        </li>
        <li
          class={`column r3 ${
            this.state.r3Price === this.state.lowestPrice ? "lowest" : ""
          }`}
        >
          {this.state.r3Price}
        </li>
      </ul>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App parsedOffers={data} />, rootElement);```
````

Comment: Sorry i may have provided my question wrong, i updated it, should be more clear now.

Answer (score 0):

You have an object, not an array. If you want to get the property name whose value is the lowest, you can use [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [Array.prototype.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) like this:

```js
const state = {
 r1Price: '200',
 r2Price: undefined,
 r3Price: '1000',
 r4Price: '100',
 r5Price: '120'
};

const lowest = Object.entries(state)
  .map(([k,v]) => [k, v ? +v : Infinity])
  .sort((a, b) => a[1] - b[1])[0];

console.log(lowest);
```

Then for each `li`, you can bind the class like this:

```
render() {
  const lowest = Object.entries(this.state)
    .map(([k,v]) => [k, v ? +v : Infinity])
    .sort((a, b) => a[1] - b[1])[0][0];

  return (
    <ul class="row">
      <li className={'column r1 ' + lowest === 'r1Price'}>{...}</li>
      <li className={'column r2 ' + lowest === 'r2Price'}>{...}</li>
      <li className={'column r3 ' + lowest === 'r3Price'}>{...}</li>
    </ul>
  );
}
```

Comment: Yes, i saw my mistake. I updated my questions few seconds ago, to make this more clear

Comment: @m4nu4l, your input is still an object, embedded in an array

Answer (score 0):

The way your object is structured you will need below code to find the lowest value.

```
let lowestNumberValue = Object.values(objData[0]).map(u=>u[0]['price']).sort((a,b)=>a>b)[0];

// above would give 200
```

Then while rendering, you could use something like

```
<li className={"column r1" + ((lowestNumberValue == this.state.r1Price) && 'lowest')}> ... </li>

<li className={"column r2" + ((lowestNumberValue == this.state.r2Price) && 'lowest')}> ... </li>
```